# chaging background color of the text on the pdf page in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, pdf

Does iOS provide any control upon the attributes of the text present on a PDF,i.e can we change the background color of the text present on the pdf, say for when a audio sync is in progress? I guess CGPDF does not provide much to control or rather extract the content information of a PDF page. Any other library that can help? Thanks !

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , yes I found a hack of just adding a Alpha reduced view on the word coordinate . Each word coordinate was stored in DB and accordingly the frame was calculated to top the layer. Hope this helps someone .